# TFS2018 clone app and data to another server, when restore TFS database got error TF400998 and TF246017

Tags: sql-server

I have a TFS server which runs SQL Server 2016 and TFS 2018.And I created scheduled backup running backup almost everyday.

Recently I plan to setup another TFS Server as the second TFS server for function/feature/backup&restore verification server.To be clear：

- The hostname of MY current TFS server is "devtfs1"
- The hostname of MY new TFS server is "devtfs2"

Which means the 2 TFS servers will be both running but devtfs1 is the production server, devtfs2 is the verification/backup.

I reference the link [Move or clone to new hardware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/move-clone-hardware?view=tfs-2018) to clone the current running TFS server"devtfs1" to new hardware "devtfs2".

On devtfs2, during the step of [Restore the TFS database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/move-clone-hardware?view=tfs-2018#restore-tfs-dbs), I got error messages like:

---

***TF400998***: The current user failed to retrieve the SQL Server service account information from devtfs1. Please make sure you have permissions to retrieve this information.

***TF246017***: Team Foundation Server could not connect to the database. Verify that the instance is specified correctly, that the server that is hosting the database is operational, and that network problems are not blocking communication with the server.

---

I gave some try but still block here, seems permission issue, but cannot find the solution from the doc.

What I can confirm:

- The two TFS servers have the same OS version, SQL Server version and
  TFS version.
- The account to setup and manage the two TFS servers are
  the same account managed by AD.

What I'm confused:

- The step of [Check Permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/move-clone-hardware?view=tfs-2018#check-permissions), it says the current account should be a member of "**TFS: Team Foundation Administrators and Admin Console Users**", which can only be set after TFS initial configuration. But the step of [Restore the TFS database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/move-clone-hardware?view=tfs-2018#restore-tfs-dbs) says install TFS but not configure TFS. So how to be a member of that group?
- Why the TF400998 report retrieve the SQL Server service account information from the current TFS server "devtfs1"? Why the db restore need to access the first TFS?

Anyone know the root cause or the solutions?

Comment: When you set up the test environment, did you choose the option during the configuration process to clone an existing environment for testing purposes? Review the purple box: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/move-clone-hardware?view=tfs-2018#clone-option-reconfigure-server-ids-and-remap-databases

Comment: Per the steps of the guide for clone TFS, I thinks I haven't reach that step. The above errors are in step to "restore TFS database" which in front of the step "(Clone option) Reconfigure server IDs and remap databases". So do you mean I need to this step before restore TFS database?